# The world crashes after reset

Tags: python, pygame, box2d, collision, reset

I have this PyBox2D function, And I want all the bodies to destroy and then reset when a Car hits a building.
The collision detection works well, so does the destroying of the world, a problem occurs when I try to reset the world.
The world would either crash, or the car moves uncontrollably or it does not move at all.

```
def _reset():
    if len(box2world.bodies) == 0:
        for building in skyscrapers:
            building.destroy_flag = False


        for wheel in cars[0].tires:
            wheel.destroy_flag = False

        cars[0].destroy_flag = False

        create_buildings()      
        create_car()
        cars[0].control()

box2world = world(contactListener=myContactListener(), gravity=(0.0, 0.0), doSleep=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the only cars you control is cars[0], the first car in the list.
when you crash into a building and _step() you are setting the destroy_flag for cars[0] to True which then destroys them, then in _reset you are setting it back to false. 
Also when you do create a car you are appending to cars. You need to reset cars to be an empty list: You are also not updating the position of car[0] while creating the new car,  only the new car in the list. Along with not emptying the skyscraper list, there are still skyscrapers in the same location as well as the car[0] in the same location.
This is causing a perpetual destroy/_reset scenario which is in turn indefinitely creating cars and skyscrapers which is then causing it to crash your world.

```
def _reset():
    if len(box2world.bodies) == 0:
        for building in skyscrapers:
            building.destroy_flag = False


        for wheel in cars[0].tires:
            wheel.destroy_flag = False

        cars[0].destroy_flag = False

        skyscrapers=[]
        cars = []
        #or you could keep your old car and just increase the index
        # to do this, instead of calling car[0], your may want to call car[carnum]
        #before creating your first car you could set the carnum to 0
        #just before creating the new car during reset you would do carnum += 1
        #another way would be instead of appending your car to a list you could do cars=[Car()]

        create_buildings()
        create_car()
        cars[0].control()
```

Comment: When I tried to run your improved _reset function I got an error that I got several times before, and so that Exception has occurred: "UnboundLocalError
local variable 'skyscrapers' referenced before assignment" How can I fix this?

Comment: Third line of your function for building in skyscrapers

Comment: I am not too certain, it works, then after the crash during _reset you get that error? or before the crash?

Comment: It happens when the function _step() is called - that means when I hit the building. I got an error that the list skyscrapers is referenced before assignment (I understand it in a way that the function knows that there is an empty list called skyscrapers created in the body of the function, but it for some reason does not know that there is already list of that name created before the function is called

Comment: The only difference i see is that you have a leading underscore, which is meant to hide the function, or keep it from being imported. Other than renaming the _functions or passing in and returning the skysrapers list i'm not sure i can help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208442/discussion-between-tanner-martin-and-mechatrnk).